# RegExp Find Numbers that have All Same Digits

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database and would like to write a REGEXP_LIKE expression that finds any number where all digits are the same, such as '999999999' or '777777777' without specifying the length of the field. Also, I would like it to be able to identify characters as well, such as 'aaaaa'.

I was able to get it working when specifying the field length, by using this:

```
select * from table1
where regexp_like (field1, '^([0-9a-z])\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1');
```

But I would like it to be able to do this for any field length.

If a field contains '7777771', for example, I would not want to see it in the results.

Comment: Does `^([0-9a-z])\1+` not work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it doesn't work, it returns values where there are any consecutive numbers. I want only the cases where every number or value is the same

Comment: @NDubonix: "it returns values where there are any consecutive numbers" --- it's not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([0-9a-z])\1+$
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mB0eN9)

Comment: Thank you! It needed the end anchor, working perfectly now. Much appreciated!

Comment: @NDubonix no problem, if you don't have any other questions please mark this question solved :)

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there.  You just need to anchor the end of the regex.

```
^([0-9a-z])\1+$
```

Comment: Strange how sometimes an identical but later answer gets all the love! +1 :)