# using regex to find same digit phone numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I need to find same digit phone numbers from a table and delete these. Phone Numbers are  like below :

```
+999999999999
11111111
0000000000000
44444444
```

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251440/regexp-find-numbers-that-have-all-same-digits) to solve this. I am trying :

```
select * from tblPhone where PhoneNo like  '^([0-9a-z])\1+$'
```

But not succeed. `PhoneNo` is varchar. How I can achieve this ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Based on the `like` expression, I would say SQL Server, but like expressions aren't that rich.

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from tblPhone
where 
substring(replace(PhoneNo,'+',''),1,len(replace(PhoneNo,'+',''))-1) 
= substring(replace(PhoneNo,'+',''),2,len(replace(PhoneNo,'+','')))
```

The idea is that if substring from 1st to second-last position matches the one from 2nd to last, the string must be composed of identical characters.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LYMU82849)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.  There is a problem with the first character, which can be a `+` or number.  Let's substitute the second character for an empty string and look at the result:

```
where replace(PhoneNo, substring(PhoneNo, 2, 1), '') in ('+', '') and
      (PhoneNo not like '%[^0-9]%' and PhoneNo like '[0-9]%'or
       PhoneNo not like '+%[^0-9]%') and PhoneNo like '+%'
      )
```

Comment: Its not giving the desired output.

Comment: Its not giving any result in tested in a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a pattern matching in SQL Server using [patindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188395.aspx) but regular expressions as such are not directly supported. There is hope, however, if you use .Net and [CLR user-defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

create table #temp(col1 varchar(25))

insert into #temp values ('+9999999')

insert into #temp values ('+123456789')

insert into #temp values ('+444444444')

insert into #temp values ('+9840536987')

select * from #temp

begin tran
select * from #temp

delete from #temp 
where cast(replace(replace(col1,'+',''),RIGHT(replace(col1,'+',''),1),0) as bigint) = 0

select * from #temp
rollback tran  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblPhone
WHERE 
  CAST(PhoneNo AS BIGINT) = REPLICATE(RIGHT(PhoneNo, 1), LEN(CAST(PhoneNo AS BIGINT)))
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblPhone
WHERE  REPLACE(PhoneNo, RIGHT(PhoneNo, 1),'') IN ('+','')
```

Answer (score 0):

This generates the set all the possible invalid phone numbers (which is a very small number) and joins that to tblPhone.  This is more efficient than doing string manipulations on every phone number in the table.

```
DELETE t1
FROM tblPhone t1
INNER JOIN (VALUES (''),('+')) t2(prefix)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')) t3(digit)
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (13) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM master.dbo.spt_values) t4(n)
ON PhoneNo = prefix+REPLICATE(digit,n)
```